# Getting error scraping web page with rvest and tidyverse

Tags: r, tidyverse, rvest

I am trying to scrape fantasy football projections via the CBS website and I'm running into an issue. Link [here](https://www.cbssports.com/fantasy/football/stats/QB/2019/1/projections/ppr/)

I have read the solutions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42989014/html-table-dont-work-with-long-row) but they did not work for me

I have tried the following code, which worked last year, but is getting an error this year. I'm assuming CBS made some changes to their site that is having an impact.

```
qbs <- read_html(paste0("https://www.cbssports.com/fantasy/football/stats/QB/2019/1/projections/ppr")) %>%
  html_nodes('table') %>%
  html_table(fill = TRUE)
```

Here is the error I'm receiving:

```
Error in if (length(p) > 1 & maxp * n != sum(unlist(nrows)) & maxp * n !=  : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue arises because the table has two header rows.

The first header row is a grouped header ("PASSING", "RUSHING", "MISC") that doesn't have as many columns as the data it represents. The second header row is not grouped and is the same length (column-wise) as the data. If we delete the first header row and keep the second, it will parse.

```
page <- read_html("https://www.cbssports.com/fantasy/football/stats/QB/2019/1/projections/ppr")

table <- page %>% 
    html_nodes('table') %>% 
    as.character()

grouped_header <- page %>% 
    html_nodes('.TableBase-headGroupTr') %>% 
    as.character()

table %>% 
    gsub(grouped_header, "", ., perl=T) %>% 
    read_html() %>% 
    html_table()
```

Comment: Thank you! How did you go about realizing that was the issue based on the error?

Comment: I dumped the html read by the first `read_html()` step to a `temp.html` file and opened it in a browser to look at it and to inspect the source code. I'm familiar with HTML and principles of tidy data. I had a hunch that there was something "extra" about the table causing a problem. I found `.TableBase-headGroupTr` by inspecting the source code using Chrome developer tools.

Comment: Appreciate the explanation! Thanks again.