# Reading html into R with rvest: problem with CSS selector

Tags: html, r, rvest

I'm following:
https://dcl-wrangle.stanford.edu/rvest.html

to parse the following html file:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/grgxdzrd98dddu5/FX17_SFpanel_subsc_PC_RFCnbtopt_nbpredoptim_accass.zip?dl=0
(using the url does not work in dropbox, so the files have to be downloaded)

I follow the indicated procedure to copy the CSS selector of the 1st table
and everything works fine:

```
> url_data <- ("FX17_SFpanel_subsc_PC_RFCnbtopt_nbpredoptim_accass.html")
> ?html_node
> css_selector <- "#report0 > table:nth-child(4)"
> url_data %>% 
+   read_html() %>% 
+   html_node(css = css_selector) %>% 
+   html_table()
           X1         X2 X3 X4 X5 X6 X7 X8 X9 X10 X11 X12 X13 X14 X15 X16 X17
1               Class ID  1  2  3  4  5  6  7   8   9  10  11  12  13  14  15
2 Class Names  Reference  1  2  3  4  5  6  7   8   9  10  11  12  13  14  15
3 Class Names Prediction  1  2  3  4  5  6  7   8   9  10  11  12  13  14  15
  X18 X19 X20 X21 X22 X23
1  16  17  18  19  20  21
2  16  17  18  19  20  21
3  16  17  18  19  20  21
```

But for the 2nd table (and similarly for the rest), I get:

```
> css_selector <- "#report0 > table:nth-child(8)"
> url_data %>% 
+   read_html() %>% 
+   html_node(css = css_selector) %>% 
+   html_table()
Error in UseMethod("html_table") : 
  no applicable method for 'html_table' applied to an object of class "xml_missing"
> url_data %>% 
+   read_html() %>% 
+   html_node(css = css_selector)
{xml_missing}
<NA>
```

Any clue?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42989014/html-table-dont-work-with-long-row

Comment: The problem is the merged/missing cells now I have viewed the data. You need to decide what to do about them. One option appears to be to remove the rows containing them as in link above. Given there is useful info there I suggest you decide how to fill the gaps and write custom functions to handle this. Is it just this file?

Comment: These files are part of the output of an opensource package (https://enmap-box.readthedocs.io/en/latest ; https://bitbucket.org/hu-geomatics/enmap-box/issues), so in principle, I can suggest that the devs modify the tables. The problem is that I do not know what to tell them exactly.

Comment: Tables 2 and 5 you can use a similar/same function to handle. Table 3 Fill = True might handle? I suspect you need to loop all rows and find the max length then back track and loop again handling where less than max.

Comment: Tell them not to use merged cells in tables and have all rows within a table of the same length (number of columns)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the merged/missing cells now I have viewed the data. You need to decide what to do about them.

Ideally, you would have the data owners not use merged cells in tables and have all rows within a table of the same length (number of columns).

Another option appears to be to remove the rows containing them as in [link][1]. Given there is useful info there I suggest you decide how to fill the gaps and write custom functions to handle this.

Below, whilst not great, is one way to handle the tables in the current format. This assumes all files will have same format - which seems likely given the mathematical nature.

Based on table number I handle tables differently to ensure equal length of rows. Sometimes I move data to headers as well. It is really a starting point for how you might sanitize the inputs.

It would be more R-esque to re-factor this to use tidyverse functions and user function calls rather than the current loop handling.

```r
library(rlang) 
library(rvest)
#> Loading required package: xml2
#> Warning: package 'xml2' was built under R version 4.0.3
library(dplyr)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'dplyr'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     filter, lag
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     intersect, setdiff, setequal, union

get_max_cols <- function(table) {
  return(length(table %>% html_nodes("tr:nth-of-type(3) th,tr:nth-of-type(3) td")))
}

get_row <- function(target, css_selector){
  row_data <- target %>% html_nodes(css_selector) %>%
    html_text() %>%
    trimws()
  return(row_data)
}

path <- "FX17_SFpanel_subsc_PC_RFCnbtopt_nbpredoptim_accass.html"
page <- read_html(path)
headers <- c("", "Reference class", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "")
first_row <- c("", "(1)", "(2)", "(3)", "(4)", "(5)", "(6)", "(7)", "(8)", "(9)", "(10)", "(11)", "(12)", "(13)", "(14)", "(15)", "(16)", "(17)", "(18)", "(19)", "(20)", "(21)", "Sum")
tables <- page %>% html_nodes("table")

for (i in seq_along(tables)) {
  table <- tables[[i]]
  max_cols <- get_max_cols(table)
  rows <- table %>% html_nodes("tr")
  num_rows <- length(rows)
  fix_flag <<- i %in% c(2, 5)
  temp_table <- data.frame(matrix(NA, nrow = if_else(fix_flag, as.integer(num_rows - 1), num_rows), ncol = max_cols))

  if (fix_flag) {
    for (r in seq_along(rows)) {
      if (r == 1) {
        temp_table <- setNames(temp_table, headers)
      } else if (r == 2) {
        temp_table[r - 1, ] <- first_row
      }
      else {
        temp_table[r - 1, ] <- get_row(rows[[r]], "th, td")
      }
    }
  }else if(i==1){
    temp_table <- table %>% html_table(fill = True)
    temp_table <- setNames(temp_table, get_row(table, 'tr:nth-of-type(1) th, tr:nth-of-type(1) td'))
    temp_table <- temp_table[-c(1),]
  }
  else {
    temp_table <- table %>% html_table(fill = True)
  }
  print(temp_table)
}
#>                 Class ID 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21
#> 2 Class Names  Reference 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21
#> 3 Class Names Prediction 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21
#>            Reference class                                                    
#> 1                      (1) (2) (3) (4) (5) (6) (7) (8) (9) (10) (11) (12) (13)
#> 2    (1) 1              54   0   0   0   0   4   0   0   0    0    0   14    0
#> 3    (2) 2               3  19   0   0   0   0   0   0   0    0    0    6    0
#> 4    (3) 3               0   0  30   0   0   0   0   0   0    0    0    0    0
#> 5    (4) 4               0   0   0  19   0   0   0   0   0    0    0    0    0
#> 6    (5) 5               0   0   0   0  62  10   4   0   0    0    0    0    0
#> 7    (6) 6               0   0   0   0  11  73   0   0   0    0    0    0    0
#> 8    (7) 7               0   0   0   0   0   4  65   0   0    0    0    3    0
#> 9    (8) 8               0   0   0   0   0   0   0  12   0    0    0    0    0
#> 10   (9) 9               0   0   0   0   0   2   0   0  19    0    0    0    0
#> 11 (10) 10               3   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   89    0    1    0
#> 12 (11) 11               0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0    0  128    0    0
#> 13 (12) 12              39   3   0   0   0   0   0   0   0    0    0  311    0
#> 14 (13) 13               0   0   0   2   0   0   0   0   0    0    0    0 1056
#> 15 (14) 14               0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0    0    0    0    0
#> 16 (15) 15               0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0    0    0    0    0
#> 17 (16) 16               3   8   0  10   0   0   0   0   0    0    0    4    0
#> 18 (17) 17               0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0    0    0    0    0
#> 19 (18) 18               2   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0    0    0    2    0
#> 20 (19) 19               0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0    0    0    0    0
#> 21 (20) 20               0   0   0   3   0   0   0   0   0    0    0    0    0
#> 22 (21) 21               0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0    0    0    0    0
#> 23     Sum             104  31  30  34  73  93  69  12  19   89  128  341 1056
#>                                                
#> 1  (14) (15) (16) (17) (18) (19) (20) (21)  Sum
#> 2     0    0    2    0    1    2    0    0   77
#> 3     0    0    7    0    0    1    0    0   36
#> 4     0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0   30
#> 5     0    0   10    0    0    0    0    0   29
#> 6     0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0   76
#> 7     0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0   84
#> 8     0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0   72
#> 9     0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0   12
#> 10    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0   21
#> 11    0    0    0    2    0    0    0    0   95
#> 12    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0  128
#> 13    0    0    0    0    1    0    0   10  364
#> 14    1    0    0    0    0    0    0    0 1059
#> 15  100    0    0    0    0    0    0    0  100
#> 16    0   27    4    6    0    0    0    0   37
#> 17    0    0  109    0    2    7    3    1  147
#> 18    0    5    0   33    0    0    0    0   38
#> 19    0    0    0    0    8    0    0    0   12
#> 20    0    0    2    0    0    2    0    0    5
#> 21    0    1    0    0    0    0   24    0   28
#> 22    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
#> 23  101   33  134   41   12   12   27   11 2450
#>            Measure Estimate [%] 95 % Confidence Interval [%]
#> 1 Overall Accuracy        91.43                         90.0
#> 2   Kappa Accuracy        88.99                        87.61
#> 3 Mean F1 Accuracy        77.60                            -
#>   95 % Confidence Interval [%]
#> 1                        92.37
#> 2                        90.37
#> 3                            -
#>              User's Accuracy [%] User's Accuracy [%] User's Accuracy [%]
#> 1  Map class            Estimate       95 % Interval       95 % Interval
#> 2      (1) 1               70.13               68.15               72.11
#> 3      (2) 2               52.78               50.85               54.71
#> 4      (3) 3               100.0               100.0               100.0
#> 5      (4) 4               65.52               63.55               67.48
#> 6      (5) 5               81.58               80.16                83.0
#> 7      (6) 6                86.9               85.28               88.53
#> 8      (7) 7               90.28               89.35                91.2
#> 9      (8) 8               100.0               100.0               100.0
#> 10     (9) 9               90.48               90.48               90.48
#> 11   (10) 10               93.68               93.68               93.68
#> 12   (11) 11               100.0               100.0               100.0
#> 13   (12) 12               85.44               84.32               86.56
#> 14   (13) 13               99.72               99.72               99.72
#> 15   (14) 14               100.0               99.61              100.39
#> 16   (15) 15               72.97               71.45                74.5
#> 17   (16) 16               74.15               72.61               75.69
#> 18   (17) 17               86.84               85.27               88.41
#> 19   (18) 18               66.67                64.8               68.53
#> 20   (19) 19                40.0               38.52               41.48
#> 21   (20) 20               85.71               84.47               86.96
#> 22   (21) 21                 0.0                 0.0                 0.0
#>    Producer's Accuracy [%] Producer's Accuracy [%] Producer's Accuracy [%]
#> 1                 Estimate            95% Interval            95% Interval
#> 2                    51.92                   42.73                   61.12
#> 3                    61.29                   47.74                   74.84
#> 4                    100.0                   100.0                   100.0
#> 5                    55.88                   40.82                   70.95
#> 6                    84.93                    77.3                   92.57
#> 7                    78.49                   72.18                   84.81
#> 8                     94.2                   87.77                  100.63
#> 9                    100.0                   100.0                   100.0
#> 10                   100.0                   88.19                  111.81
#> 11                   100.0                   95.34                  104.66
#> 12                   100.0                   100.0                   100.0
#> 13                    91.2                   88.69                   93.71
#> 14                   100.0                   99.69                  100.31
#> 15                   99.01                   99.01                   99.01
#> 16                   81.82                   69.79                   93.84
#> 17                   81.34                   75.88                    86.8
#> 18                   80.49                    71.1                   89.87
#> 19                   66.67                   43.27                   90.06
#> 20                   16.67                  -23.88                   57.22
#> 21                   88.89                   77.23                  100.55
#> 22                     0.0                     nan                     nan
#>    F1 Accuracy  F1 Accuracy  F1 Accuracy
#> 1     Estimate 95% Interval 95% Interval
#> 2        59.67        56.93         62.4
#> 3        56.72        54.02        59.42
#> 4        100.0        100.0        100.0
#> 5        60.32        57.56        63.07
#> 6        83.22        81.25        85.19
#> 7        82.49        80.26        84.71
#> 8         92.2         90.9        93.49
#> 9        100.0        100.0        100.0
#> 10        95.0         95.0         95.0
#> 11       96.74        96.74        96.74
#> 12       100.0        100.0        100.0
#> 13       88.23        86.78        89.67
#> 14       99.86        99.86        99.86
#> 15        99.5         99.5         99.5
#> 16       77.14         75.0        79.29
#> 17       77.58        75.48        79.68
#> 18       83.54        81.36        85.73
#> 19       66.67        64.04         69.3
#> 20       23.53        21.44        25.61
#> 21       87.27        85.52        89.02
#> 22         0.0          0.0          0.0
#>            Reference class                                                 
#> 1                      (1)    (2)    (3)    (4)    (5)    (6)    (7)    (8)
#> 2    (1) 1           0.022    0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0 0.0016    0.0    0.0
#> 3    (2) 2          0.0012 0.0078    0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0
#> 4    (3) 3             0.0    0.0 0.0122    0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0
#> 5    (4) 4             0.0    0.0    0.0 0.0078    0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0
#> 6    (5) 5             0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0 0.0253 0.0041 0.0016    0.0
#> 7    (6) 6             0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0 0.0045 0.0298    0.0    0.0
#> 8    (7) 7             0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0 0.0016 0.0265    0.0
#> 9    (8) 8             0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0 0.0049
#> 10   (9) 9             0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0 0.0008    0.0    0.0
#> 11 (10) 10          0.0012    0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0
#> 12 (11) 11             0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0
#> 13 (12) 12          0.0159 0.0012    0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0
#> 14 (13) 13             0.0    0.0    0.0 0.0008    0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0
#> 15 (14) 14             0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0
#> 16 (15) 15             0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0
#> 17 (16) 16          0.0012 0.0033    0.0 0.0041    0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0
#> 18 (17) 17             0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0
#> 19 (18) 18          0.0008    0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0
#> 20 (19) 19             0.0 0.0004    0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0
#> 21 (20) 20             0.0    0.0    0.0 0.0012    0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0
#> 22 (21) 21             0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0
#> 23     Sum          0.0424 0.0127 0.0122 0.0139 0.0298  0.038 0.0282 0.0049
#>                                                                               
#> 1     (9)   (10)   (11)   (12)  (13)   (14)   (15)   (16)   (17)   (18)   (19)
#> 2     0.0    0.0    0.0 0.0057   0.0    0.0    0.0 0.0008    0.0 0.0004 0.0008
#> 3     0.0    0.0    0.0 0.0024   0.0    0.0    0.0 0.0029    0.0    0.0 0.0004
#> 4     0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0   0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0
#> 5     0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0   0.0    0.0    0.0 0.0041    0.0    0.0    0.0
#> 6     0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0   0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0
#> 7     0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0   0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0
#> 8     0.0    0.0    0.0 0.0012   0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0
#> 9     0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0   0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0
#> 10 0.0078    0.0    0.0    0.0   0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0
#> 11    0.0 0.0363    0.0 0.0004   0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0 0.0008    0.0    0.0
#> 12    0.0    0.0 0.0522    0.0   0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0
#> 13    0.0    0.0    0.0 0.1269   0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0 0.0004    0.0
#> 14    0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0 0.431 0.0004    0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0
#> 15    0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0   0.0 0.0408    0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0
#> 16    0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0   0.0    0.0  0.011 0.0016 0.0024    0.0    0.0
#> 17    0.0    0.0    0.0 0.0016   0.0    0.0    0.0 0.0445    0.0 0.0008 0.0029
#> 18    0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0   0.0    0.0  0.002    0.0 0.0135    0.0    0.0
#> 19    0.0    0.0    0.0 0.0008   0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0 0.0033    0.0
#> 20    0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0   0.0    0.0    0.0 0.0008    0.0    0.0 0.0008
#> 21    0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0   0.0    0.0 0.0004    0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0
#> 22    0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0   0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0
#> 23 0.0078 0.0363 0.0522 0.1392 0.431 0.0412 0.0135 0.0547 0.0167 0.0049 0.0049
#>                        
#> 1    (20)   (21)    Sum
#> 2     0.0    0.0 0.0314
#> 3     0.0    0.0 0.0147
#> 4     0.0    0.0 0.0122
#> 5     0.0    0.0 0.0118
#> 6     0.0    0.0  0.031
#> 7     0.0    0.0 0.0343
#> 8     0.0    0.0 0.0294
#> 9     0.0    0.0 0.0049
#> 10    0.0    0.0 0.0086
#> 11    0.0    0.0 0.0388
#> 12    0.0    0.0 0.0522
#> 13    0.0 0.0041 0.1486
#> 14    0.0    0.0 0.4322
#> 15    0.0    0.0 0.0408
#> 16    0.0    0.0 0.0151
#> 17 0.0012 0.0004   0.06
#> 18    0.0    0.0 0.0155
#> 19    0.0    0.0 0.0049
#> 20    0.0    0.0  0.002
#> 21 0.0098    0.0 0.0114
#> 22    0.0    0.0    0.0
#> 23  0.011 0.0045    1.0
#>              Proportion    Proportion    Proportion Area [px]     Area [px]
#> 1  Map class   Estimate 95 % Interval 95 % Interval  Estimate 95 % Interval
#> 2      (1) 1     0.0314        0.0247        0.0382       0.0           0.0
#> 3      (2) 2     0.0147        0.0112        0.0182       0.0           0.0
#> 4      (3) 3     0.0122        0.0122        0.0122       0.0           0.0
#> 5      (4) 4     0.0118         0.008        0.0157       0.0           0.0
#> 6      (5) 5      0.031        0.0275        0.0345       0.0           0.0
#> 7      (6) 6     0.0343        0.0296         0.039       0.0           0.0
#> 8      (7) 7     0.0294        0.0272        0.0316       0.0           0.0
#> 9      (8) 8     0.0049        0.0049        0.0049       0.0           0.0
#> 10     (9) 9     0.0086        0.0086        0.0086       0.0           0.0
#> 11   (10) 10     0.0388        0.0388        0.0388       0.0           0.0
#> 12   (11) 11     0.0522        0.0522        0.0522       0.0           0.0
#> 13   (12) 12     0.1486        0.1427        0.1545       0.0           0.0
#> 14   (13) 13     0.4322        0.4322        0.4322       0.0           0.0
#> 15   (14) 14     0.0408        0.0397        0.0419       0.0           0.0
#> 16   (15) 15     0.0151        0.0125        0.0177       0.0           0.0
#> 17   (16) 16       0.06        0.0549        0.0651       0.0           0.0
#> 18   (17) 17     0.0155        0.0126        0.0185       0.0           0.0
#> 19   (18) 18     0.0049        0.0028         0.007       0.0           0.0
#> 20   (19) 19      0.002       -0.0007        0.0048       0.0          -0.0
#> 21   (20) 20     0.0114        0.0095        0.0133       0.0           0.0
#> 22   (21) 21        0.0       -0.0026        0.0026       0.0          -0.0
#>        Area [px]
#> 1  95 % Interval
#> 2            0.0
#> 3            0.0
#> 4            0.0
#> 5            0.0
#> 6            0.0
#> 7            0.0
#> 8            0.0
#> 9            0.0
#> 10           0.0
#> 11           0.0
#> 12           0.0
#> 13           0.0
#> 14           0.0
#> 15           0.0
#> 16           0.0
#> 17           0.0
#> 18           0.0
#> 19           0.0
#> 20           0.0
#> 21           0.0
#> 22           0.0
```

<sup>Created on 2021-03-09 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Thanks, this solves the problem. Just note that library(rlang) is required. In the future, the confusion matrix will be provided in a more R-friendly format and all the rest can be calculated from it in R

Comment: Coolio. Glad if it helped/solved problem. Was interesting. Not sure why rlang is prompted for you. I definitely don't have it loaded unless via a different package. RStudio seems to remember things and I never have the right bit of code to hand to expunge all the loaded libraries. NVM... thanks, I have added it to the imports in case helps some one else. :-)